# Ant Compile Error - Tesseract for Android

Tags: android, ubuntu, ant, tesseract

I am following a guide to get Tesseract for android working. The last instruction is to run ant-compile. If i run this command i get an error saying;

```
BUILD FAILED Target "compile" does not exist in the project "tesseract-android-tools".
```

I am unsure what this actually means, and therfore I can't really guess how to solve it. Please could i get some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try `ant release` instead.